# Why can't I submit data in a query, and get data in a mutation in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I read through all of graphql's documentation and at least 4 blogs explaining graphql's query and mutation concepts, but what I haven't found in any of those resources is why do we have to use a query to get data, and why do we have to use a mutation to submit data?

Looking at their schemes they look really similar in terms of describing a root query/mutation, then defining a type+resolver. Both queries and mutations are written that way.

Why is it not ok to use mutation to get data, or use query to submit data when the composition looks very similar?

**Query**:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Root',
  fields: () => ({
    viewer: {
      type: Viewer,
      resolve: () => getViewer()
    }
  })
});
```

**Mutation**:

```
var MutationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ArticleGraph Mutations',
  description: 'These are the things we can change',
  fields: () => ({
    deleteArticle: {
      type: ArticleType,
      description: 'Delete an article with id and return the article that was deleted.',
      args: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) }
      },
      resolve: (value, { id }) => {
        return ArticleServices.delete(id);
      }
    }
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* put all the mutation stuff behind queries, just like you could implement every endpoint as a `GET` in a RESTful framework.  Nothing's stopping you.

But the same reason we have `GET`, `POST`, and other HTTP verbs in non-graphql systems applies here.  It is very useful to draw a bright red line between idempotent "get me some data" operations and side-effectey "change some stuff" operations.

Also from a practical standpoint, graphql systems combine the **entire** surface area of an application into a single endpoint.  It would not be the greatest developer ergonomics to arbitrarily mix in the `read` and `write` stuff.  Some labeling needs to happen.

And, perhaps most importantly, that's how Facebook chose to implement it.